# Problem with Analysing Turkish Text while using stopwords "tr" with R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am analysing Turkish text in R. But there is a problem when using stopwords"tr" 
Although, in indicated link, Turkish language is represented with "tr" But it still does not recognize it.

here is the error:

Error: Language "tr" not available in source "snowball". See `stopwords_getlanguages` for more information on supported languages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the R-Tag, "R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use stats.stackexchange.com."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to change the `source` of where the `stopwords::stopwords` get the language from.

#### tldr:

For running your code you need:

```
stopwords::stopwords("tr", source = "stopwords-iso")
[1] "acaba"      "acep"       "adamakıllı" "adeta"      "ait"        "altmýþ"  ...
```

#### Explanation:

These are the languages available in the default source = "snowball"

```
stopwords::stopwords_getlanguages(source = "snowball")
[1] "da" "de" "en" "es" "fi" "fr" "hu" "ir" "it" "nl" "no" "pt" "ro" "ru" "sv"
```

To get Turkish you just need to change the source to `source = "stopwords-iso"`. Below you can see all the stopwords available in this source.

```
stopwords::stopwords_getlanguages(source = "stopwords-iso")
 [1] "af" "ar" "hy" "eu" "bn" "br" "bg" "ca" "zh" "hr" "cs" "da" "nl" "en" "eo" "et" "fi" "fr" "gl" "de" "el" "ha" "he" "hi" "hu" "id" "ga"
[28] "it" "ja" "ko" "ku" "la" "lt" "lv" "ms" "mr" "no" "fa" "pl" "pt" "ro" "ru" "sk" "sl" "so" "st" "es" "sw" "sv" "th" "tl" "tr" "uk" "ur"
[55] "vi" "yo" "zu"
```

Which means that for running your code you need:

```
stopwords::stopwords("tr", source = "stopwords-iso")
[1] "acaba"      "acep"       "adamakıllı" "adeta"      "ait"        "altmýþ"  ...
```